# Game Of Thrones (Telltale) PC won't pick up Xbox One controller

Tags: pc, controllers, game-of-thrones

I plugged in my Xbox One controller via USB, started Game of Thrones, and it doesn't register that the controller is plugged in.  The Controls section in Settings just shows me mouse and WASD.

Other people online say it works automatically, and the Steam page says full controller support.  I've also tested with other games and the controller has registered immediately.  What could be going wrong?

Comment: For some games, my controller works on USB3 ports. You might want to try that.